# How to remove an object's property when using the spread syntax in order to create a new instance of an object?

Tags: typescript, properties, spread-syntax

Given these two Interfaces:

```
interface IFoo {
    foos: string[];
    fnord: string;
}

interface IFooFlat {
    foo: string;
    fnord: string;
}
```

I want to convert an array of `IFoo` into `IFooFlat` via this map function:

```
const foos: IFoo[] = [
    {
        foos: [
            "narf",
            "poit"
        ],
        fnord: "fnord"
    }
];

const flattened: IFooFlat[][] = foos.map((fooObject: IFoo): IFooFlat[] => {
    fooObject.foos.map((fooItem: string): IFooFlat => {
        return {
            ...fooObject,
            foo: fooItem,
        };

    });
});
```

Yet this will generate the error:

```
Type '{ foo: string; foos: string[]; fnord: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IFooFlat'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'foos' does not exist in type 'IFooFlat'.
```

I now want to remove the `foos` property yet I do not want to apply each property explicitly (my real world case example has many more properties), I only want to delete a very specific property, namely foo.

Hence, I tried creating a clone and deleting the property, yet it fails while throwing the same error:

```
const flattened = foos.map((foosObject: IFoo): IFooFlat[] => {
    const clone = Object.assign(foosObject, {});
    delete clone.foos;

    return foosObject.foos.map((oneFooString: string): IFooFlat => {
        return {
            ...clone,
            foo: oneFooString,
        };
    });
});
```

How can I delete a property from an object in TypeScript?

Comment: [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is _not_ an operator.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the destructuring syntax with the spread syntax to achieve what you want:

```
const flattened = foos.map((foosObject: IFoo): IFooFlat[] => {
    const { foos, ...clone } = foosObject; // clone will contain all properties but `foos`.

    return foos.map((oneFooString: string): IFooFlat => {
        return {
            ...clone,
            foo: oneFooString,
        };
    });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(flattened, null, 4));
```

will print:

```
[
    [
        {
            "fnord": "fnord",
            "foo": "narf"
        },
        {
            "fnord": "fnord",
            "foo": "poit"
        }
    ]
]
```